# How can I make an authenticated http request and return a stream of objects with dart?

Tags: mobile, dart, http-headers, flutter, http-get

I have to put the API Key in the request header as:

> Authorization: Bearer "YOUR API KEY"

This is my code (**I'm not sure where to put the header and how**)

```
Future<Stream<Book>> getBooks() async {
  var url = ‘example_url’

  var client = http.Client();
  var streamedResponse = await client.send(
    http.Request(‘get’, Uri.parse(url))
  );

  return streamedResponse.stream
    .transform(utf.decoder)
    .transform(json.decoder)
    .expand(jsonBody) => (jsonBody as Map)[‘results’] )
    .map((jsonBook) = Book.fromJson(jsonBook));
}
```

The Flutter docs https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests/ says to use this format for authenticated requests but this is not for streams, this returns a future of an object (Book)

```
Future<Book> fetchPost() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Place your_api_token_here"},
  );
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

  return Book.fromJson(responseJson);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom headers after you created the `Request`

```
final request = http.Request('GET'), url)
      ..headers.addAll(myHeaders);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a custom header using http.Request as follow bellow :

```
final url =
    'https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.6.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso';
final request = Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
request.headers.clear();
request.headers.addAll({"content-type":"application/json"});
```